# PHP error on printing array[i] in for

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $array = range(1,10);

    echo 'out func Array for Before : <br />';
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        echo $array[i]; // This Line!!
    echo 'End of Array Found.<br />';

    function my_multiply(&$value, $key, $factor){

        echo 'in func value(Before) - '.$value.'<br />';
        $value *= $factor;
        echo 'in func value(After) - '.$value.'<br />';
    }
    array_walk(&$array, 'my_multiply', 3);

    echo 'out func Array for Aefore : <br />';
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
            echo $array[i]; //This Line Too.
    echo 'End of Array Found.<br />';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to print array[i] using echo function. but It doesn't print anything!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Er9.png)

Comment: you missed $ write this way `$array[$i]`;

Comment: ```i``` is not a variable. Could you use: $array[$i]

Comment: PHP 7.2 says: *"Warning: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"*. It used to be a notice in previous versions and your interpreter is probably configured to not report the notices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `$` near `i`.

So this:-

```
echo $array[i];//forgot $ near i
```

Need to be:-

```
echo $array[$i];// now $i is correct variable and will work fine
```

Every-where

Comment: Thank you! i First learn php...

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the answer.

Comment: @WishSKY  glad to help you :):)